# How to get different sized media - Twitter API

Tags: twitter

A Twitter API request may get a tweet with an image, returning JSON that contains something like this (non-relevant bits removed)

```
["media"]=>
array(1) {
    ...
    [0]=>
    array(14) {
        ...
        ["media_url"]=>
        string(46) "http://pbs.twimg.com/media/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.jpg"
        ...
        ["type"]=>
        string(5) "photo"
        ["sizes"]=>
        array(4) {
            ["medium"]=>
            array(3) {
                ["w"]=>
                int(1200)
                ["h"]=>
                int(1200)
                ["resize"]=>
                string(3) "fit"
            }
            ["large"]=>
            array(3) {
                ["w"]=>
                int(2048)
                ["h"]=>
                int(2048)
                ["resize"]=>
                string(3) "fit"
            }
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

How do you access the different sized versions of the image? I tried entering "http://pbs.twimg.com/media/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX_medium.jpg" or "http://pbs.twimg.com/media/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX_1200x1200.jpg" into the address bar (obviously with real images, as opposed to this example URL) but that doesn't come up with anything

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The syntax is slightly confusing, but is [described in the Twitter documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/entities-in-twitter-objects).

The size name `medium` needs to be added *to the end* of the URl.

For example:

- https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CqnMeKkW8AAYDsc.jpg:thumb
- https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CqnMeKkW8AAYDsc.jpg:small
- https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CqnMeKkW8AAYDsc.jpg:medium
- https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CqnMeKkW8AAYDsc.jpg:large
- https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CqnMeKkW8AAYDsc.jpg:orig (original size image, with metadata stripped out)